# Node.js: How to change log level without restarting the server?

Tags: node.js, environment-variables, winston, loggly

In the Node.js application, I use Winston for logging. Right now, the `winston.level` is set from `process.env.LOG_LEVEL` variable.

How to reset the `winston.level` whenever there is a change in `process.env.LOG_LEVEL` without restarting the Node process or server.

Comment: how is the change to `process.env.LOG_LEVEL` made in your server?

Comment: it can be any possible way, 
1. Modifying it in .bash_profile
2. Using export command
3. Through docker image or Kubernetes dashboard

Comment: yes but you'd have to restart the process for the changes to take effect. I dont see any other way.

Comment: If not environment variables, is there any approach to solve my problem ?

Comment: I'd totally advance against doing that in fact. You will only introduce a security hole in your application if you can change environment variables the way you want. Configuration should be read-only and immutable. If it needs to change then it's good practice to do that during build time on your CI/CD server.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use **debug** npm module to do the trick. This code will help you to enable or disable debug logs without restarting your node application.

You can use **debug** module along with winston, where winston will log normal application logs, and for debugging you have to use this module.

```
/**
 *  To test this code 
 *  1. npm install debug express and npm start = to run a server
 *  2. goto http://localhost:8181/ = (simmulate running batch process) to start the logging on every second
 *  3. goto http://localhost:8181/change/myapp:db = to eable debug log
 *  4. goto http://localhost:8181/disable = to disable debug log
 * 
 *  Note: Don't foget to monitor your console, after each request. :P
 */
const debug = require('debug');
const express = require('express');

const intiLog = debug('myapp:init');
const batchProcessLog = debug('myapp:batch');
const dbLog = debug('myapp:db');

const app = express();

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    setInterval(() => {
        console.log('This normal console.log');
        intiLog('This is init log');
        batchProcessLog('Hey this is batch process');
        dbLog('This is DB logs');
    }, 1000);
    return res.status(200).send('OK');
});

// nameSpance = myapp:init => enable only one log
// nameSpace = myapp:db,myapp:myappbatch => enable multiple log
// nameSpace = myapp:*,-myapp:init => enable all log except myapp:init log
app.get('/change/:nameSpace', (req, res) => {
    const { nameSpace } = req.params;
    debug.enable(nameSpace);
    return res.status(200).send(`May the force be with you ${nameSpace}`);
});

app.get('/disable', (req, res) => {
    debug.disable();    
    return res.status(200).send(`See you than...`);
});


app.listen(8181, () => console.log(`Running app on ${8181}`));
```

**Note: This code might not be ready for production use**

For security reason you should put this API behind *Authentication* and *Authorization* check.

Comment: Nice workaround !! right now I will accept this as solution, but if better solution comes in, I would chose it :P

Comment: Yes sure I am also willing to see different approach. :)

Comment: @VinayPandya What do you think about using node processes to achieve it?
https://www.npmjs.com/package/runtime-node-refresh

Answer (score 0):

@KamalakannanJ you might try to use **RnR** library to change winston log level on runtime without restarting the node server.

Here is the link:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/runtime-node-refresh